# Como obtengo el subtotal de una tabla alterna mysql

Tags: mysql

Quiero tomar la columna "Precio" de la tabla "Productos" e ingresar esa informacion a la columna "subtotal" de la tabla "ventas", por medio del "idproducto" que es la llave que une ambas para poder localizar el precio que corresponde para cada venta.

soy nueva en mysql asi que no se mucho de los diferentes tipos de tablas y variables, si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradeceria.

les dejo el codigo de las tablas:

```
create table productos
(
    Idproductos int not null auto_increment primary key,
    Codigo varchar(15) not null,
    Producto varchar(50) not null,
    Cantidad int not null,
    Precio int,
    tipoprod varchar(50)
);
insert into productos(Codigo, Producto, Cantidad, Precio, tipoprod) values("003","Simparica",2,150,"Vacuna antirrabica");
insert into productos(Codigo, Producto, Cantidad, Precio, tipoprod) values("015","Seresto",5,450,"Collar antipulgas");
insert into productos(Codigo, Producto, Cantidad, Precio, tipoprod) values("063","Pet Pectillin",3,75,"Medicamento intestinal");
insert into productos(Codigo, Producto, Cantidad, Precio, tipoprod) values("074","Omega Vet",4,230,"Suplemento");
insert into productos(Codigo, Producto, Cantidad, Precio, tipoprod) values("012","ActiPet",1,100,"Vitaminas");
select * from productos;


create table ventas
(
    Idventa int not null auto_increment primary key,
    Nombreclien varchar(50) not null,
    Telefonoclien varchar(50) not null,
    Direccionclien varchar(50) not null,
    Pago varchar(50) not null,
    Cantidad int not null,
    Subtotal float,
    Idproductos int not null,
    foreign key(Idproductos) references productos(Idproductos)
);
SELECT SUM(precio=subtotal) FROM productos, ventas;
insert into ventas(Nombreclien, Telefonoclien, Direccionclien, Pago, Cantidad, Subtotal, Idproductos) values("Larry",1234674525,"zona 14","Efectivo",12,Subtotal,1);
select * from ventas;
```

en una parte de ventas se puede notar que intente usar ciclos pero no funcionaron.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tratas de hacer algo así:

```
UPDATE ventas
  JOIN (
    SELECT Idproductos,
      Cantidad*Precio Subtotal
      FROM productos  
  ) c1 USING(Idproductos)
  set ventas.Subtotal=cantidad*c1.Subtotal;
```

Para obtener:

```
+---------+-------------+---------------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+-------------+
| Idventa | Nombreclien | Telefonoclien | Direccionclien | Pago     | Cantidad | Subtotal | Idproductos |
+---------+-------------+---------------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+-------------+
|       1 | Larry       | 1234674525    | zona 14        | Efectivo |       12 |     3600 |           1 |
+---------+-------------+---------------+----------------+----------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Salvo que cada cliente comprara un único producto, tendrías un fallo de diseño en tu modelo de datos, pues la entidad `productos` no debería contener el atributo `Cantidad`, ni la entidad `ventas` el atributo `Idproductos`. Estos dos atributos deberían pertenecer a una relación entre las entidades `ventas` y `productos`. En el modelo relacional, una tabla `venden` con los campos `Idproductos` y `Cantidad`. También sería conveniente separar los clientes de las `ventas`, pues entiendo que un cliente podría comprar más de una vez y entonces tendrías datos redundantes.

La propuesta sería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]